# How can I specify an exit code with Purescript

Tags: purescript

If I run the following using `pulp run` the process ends with status 0.

```
main :: forall e. Eff (console :: CONSOLE | e) Int
main = do
  log "Hello sailor!"
  pure 137
```

How can I exit the program with an error without throwing an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running on Node (which is what `pulp run` does), you should use Node facilities for this. Specifically, the function you want is [Node.Process.exit](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-node-process/5.0.0/docs/Node.Process#v:exit):

```
import Node.Process(exit)

main = do
    log "Hello sailor!"
    exit 137
```